# iOS5 Consuming a PHP web service for login

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services

I am developing photo sharing app in iOS5. In this, I need to implement login through PHP web service. I implementyed PHP Web service and also i got json string well. Now How can i check whether the user is logged in or not when the application launches and also how can i save username and password when user first login? Please provide me the solution as soon as possible. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checking the status of login user when you send the logine details through web services you can set a flag of the login status in the database and each and every time you can check it for the login status.

for the username and password save in iphone application you can check following links :

[How do save username and password in my twitter application in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324257/how-do-save-username-and-password-in-my-twitter-application-in-iphone)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323411/how-to-save-and-read-the-username-and-password-in-iphone

Answer (score 1):

I used a REST server for a similar iphone application. I created a REST server endpoint at the website end. There was a **specific** url just to test whether a user was logged in or not.

I hit this url inside my iphone application. I used an NSURLRequest and obtained the json object returned by the REST server. If the user was logged in, the json object contained the username. If user was not logged in, a different json object was obtained.

I do not know how you are implementing web services, but there should be a method you can call just to get the login status. You can then examine the json object returned.

Comment: web service is implemented through rest in PHP